# How to get sub image from buffered image

Tags: java, image

We can get a sub image from BufferedImage using `getSubimage(int,int,int,int)`,
but my problem is I want to get exact subimage(rectangle image) by passing double values as `width` and `height`. Is there any alternative for that ?

Answer (score 8):

cast the double values to int.

```
getSubImage((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
```

and as @camickr mentioned The internal cells will still be represented by **integer** pixel values. If each cell is 5 pixels square. The first cell starts at (0, 0), the second cell starts at (5, 0) etc...

Comment: if we do cast then we may loss exactness , i need exact subimage. Thank you very much

Comment: Explain further what you would expect it to do as it is not possible to return fractional pixels. For most use cases rounding to the nearest pixel is a better solution then going for a computational expensive solution that slightly scales the image (to line up the pixels) causing quality loss.

Comment: I've a rectangle field which contains 24 internal cells, I need a sub image of each cell

Comment: @Jagan, The internal cells will still be represented by integer pixel values. If each cell is 5 pixels square. The first cell starts at (0, 0), the second cell starts at (5, 0) etc...